# ¿Cómo hacer una serie de Taylor de la función coseno en Java?

Tags: java, loops

Como puedo calcular el coseno de 60 grados con una serie de Taylor haciendo un ciclo que calcule los términos y los acumule. Además que pare cuando el término que se acaba de calcular sea menor que 0.0001.

Hasta ahora lo he hecho así, pero me da -1 cuando debería darme 0.5

```
double x = 60;
double n = 1;
double sumatoria = 0;
double base = -1;
double exponente = 0;

while (Math.abs(sumatoria) < 0.0001) {
    double acumulador;
    acumulador = base;
    for (double i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        acumulador = acumulador * base;
    }
    double resultado = 1;
    for (double j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        resultado = resultado * j;
    }
    double c = 2 * n;
    sumatoria = sumatoria + ((acumulador / resultado) * Math.pow(60, c));
    n++;
}
System.out.println(sumatoria);
```

Comment: @x-rw gracias por decirme

Comment: a que serie de taylor te refieres?

Comment: @x-rw la de la funcion coseno la que es cos x= sumatoria de n=0 hasta infinito ((-1)^n)/(2n)!  x^2n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas.
Según la formula

[image: Imagen]

Un programa en Java para calcular la serie es:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double angulo = Math.toRadians(60),
                calcularPorSerie = serieTaylor(angulo),
                calcularPorMath = Math.cos(angulo);

        System.out.println("Serie: " + calcularPorSerie);
        System.out.println("Cos: " + calcularPorMath);
    }

    static double serieTaylor(double x) {
        double sumando, sumatoria = 0, precision = 0.0001d;

        // limite superior, iteracion de la sumatoria
        int n = 0; 

        do {
            sumando = Math.pow(-1, n) / factorial(2 * n) * Math.pow(x, 2 * n);
            sumatoria = sumatoria + sumando;
            n = n + 1;
        } while (Math.abs(sumando) > precision);

        return sumatoria;
    }

    static double factorial(int numero) {
        double factorial = 1.0d;

        while (numero != 0) {
            factorial *= numero--;
        }

        return factorial;
    }
}
```

Recordar que los ángulos se expresan en Radianes.