# ¿Cómo hacer una Serie de Taylor para la función coseno en PSeInt?

Tags: algoritmos, pseint

Necesito escribir un algoritmo en *PSeInt* del coseno en radianes, por el método de la [serie de Taylor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_de_Taylor), tengo el algoritmo del seno y lo único que se me ocurre es cambiar el valor de contador de `1` a `0`, pero el resultado es incorrecto.

Este e el código que tengo:

```
Algoritmo sintitulo
    constante=4*atan(1)
    APRECIABLE=0.0000000001
    mascasos=1
    escribir "calcular valores de la funcion seno mediante series"
    Mientras mascasos=1
        Escribir "dame un angulo en radianes   " 
        leer x
        si x>0 entonces
            Mientras x>=2*constante 
                x=x-2*constante

            FinMientras
        sino    
            mientras  x<=-2*constante
                x=x+2*constante
            FinMientras
        FinSi
        signo=1
        contador=0
        denominador=1
        termino=x
        suma=x
        Escribir "signo*termino            suma"
        Mientras (abs(termino)>=apreciable)
            contador=contador+2
            numerador=x^contador
            denominador=denominador*(contador-1)*contador
            termino=numerador/denominador
            signo=-signo
            suma=suma+signo*termino

            Escribir signo*termino, "   ", suma
        FinMientras
        escribir "el coseno de " x," es " suma
        mascasos=0
        mientras mascasos<1 O mascasos >2
            Escribir "procesar mas casos?    1--si  2--no  "
            Escribir "su opcion?  "
            Leer mascasos
        FinMientras
    FinMientras
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: si te sirve http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51799/como-hacer-una-serie-de-taylor-de-la-funci%C3%B3n-coseno/51897#51897 , por cierto, pon código, con imágenes es difícil entender que código tienes, ademas que no se puede reproducir.

Comment: vale ya coloque el codigo, y pues el enlace que me mandaste esta escrito en java y acabo de empezar a ver algoritmos y solo en pseint xd pero gracias :)

Comment: muchas gracias, pero aun no escribimos algoritmos con funciones así, se supone que debo hacerlo como el codigo de arriba, pero la verdad no tengo ni idea de por que cuando pruebo el codigo por ejemplo en un angulo de 1.5 radianes me da como resultado 0.570737201 y deberia dar 0.070737201 :´c

Comment: si muchas gracias,perdón por ser tan novato, hace una semana me enseñaron algoritmos, y pues por desesperación lo publique aquí xd,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un algoritmo para calcular el coseno en PSeint es

```
Algoritmo SerieTaylor 
    Escribir "Ingrese un numero(en radianes): "

    // leer angulo
    Leer angulo 

    // este es el resultado de cada iteracion de la sumatoria
    iteracion = 0 

    // este es el total de la sumatoria
    sumatoria = 0 

    // la presicion con la que se calcula el coseno
    precision = 0.0001 

    // numero de iteracion n = 0 , n -> iteracion < precicion
    n = 0 
    Hacer 
        // calcular el factorial
        factorial = 1 
        num = n * 2
        Mientras num != 0 
            factorial = factorial * num 
            num = num - 1 
        FinMientras 

        // calcular la sumatoria principal
        iteracion = ((-1) ^ n) / factorial * (angulo ^ (2 * n)) 
        sumatoria = sumatoria + iteracion 

        // aumentar n de la sumatoria
        n = n + 1 
    Hasta Que abs(iteracion) < precision 

    Escribir "Resultado: " sumatoria
FinAlgoritmo
```